# SQL - inner join before left join

Tags: sql

I have come across some sql that has an inner join right before a left join.

```
From Table t
     INNER JOIN vw_User i ON t.UserID = i.UserID
     LEFT JOIN UserTypeTwo it ON t.UserTypeTwoID = it.UserTypeTwoID
```

Can someone please help me visualize how this works. I can visualize the two joins separately, but since they are one after the other, how do they work together?

Comment: Here is some info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matters-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following image, don't have enough rep to embed it. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S8fF.png

Answer (score 0):

What will happens is that you are just appending more columns to `Table T`.
Basically what happens is that `Table T` has no relationship to `UserTypeTwo`, but it does to `vw_user`. Then you need some data from `UserTypeTwo` but since `Table T` can't join to `userTypeTwo` you need a table to connect them both, which is where `vw_user` comes in which should have a relation to `UserTypeTwo`.

Basically this query is being used because you need columns from `Table T` and `UserTypeTwo`(and probably vw_User as well) so you need to join all three of them.

- `Table T` has `FK` for `vw_User`
- `vw_User` has `FK` to `UserTypeTwo`
- `UserTypeTwo` has column that you need

(it doesnt necessarily need to be a foreign key but I'm assuming you know this since you have join knowledge).

I hope I was able to clarify what is happening.

Comment: Table t is related to UserTypeTwo by the UserTypeTwoID

Comment: Opps sorry scanned through that very quickly, but regardless all you are doing is appending more columns to table t. Its very common that you need different columns from different tables that the Main table has relations to, so basically it works by first it inner joins T with vw_User, and now it has all of those columns and then it joins that result to UserTypeTwo.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, no better way to express joins than like this:

[image]

Comment: I refer to this visual all the time. I just don't understand how combing two joins one after the other affects the visual.