# why we have need of left and right join

Tags: mysql, join

I have been asked in an interview that why we need left and right join separately while we can get same result by using any of them by changing the order of table? Please help me.

Comment: You don't need both -- but would you rather make 3 lefts when 1 right turn can do?  Just kidding of course, it's just standard sql.  To each his own -- I prefer `left join` myself though.  Others think "backwards" and prefer `right join`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have 2 tables to join, then **yes**, you will **not** see the difference at all.

But for 3 or more tables, the **order** of the tables being joined matters.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql#answer-9615296) to see examples of it.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the language doesn't need both.  In fact, I avoid `right join` and see no issues at all.  `Left join` is preferable for two reasons.  First, the logic is simpler to me -- keep all rows in the first table and then matching rows in the second and subsequent tables.  More importantly, SQL queries are parsed left to right so:

```
from a left join b left join c
```

is parsed as

```
from (a left join b) left join c
```

If you work out some complex examples, you will see that this structure of parsing is more intuitive with `left join` than `right join`.

Of course, databases support both forms because the ANSI standard requires it.  And, if some people have different preferences, they can use `right join` as much as they want.