# Use of more then one join and left join

Tags: sql-server-2012

If I got more then one join and in the second join I use left join. 
by using this clause its going to take all the data from the two first tables or only from the second table.

Thanks

Comment: all the data from the joined tables

Answer (score 1):

**Join** is just a method to connect different tables. Theoretically (not computationally), there's no limit on the number of  joins you used on a query.

Keep in mind that the order of joins are important once you started to use something other than `inner` joins. For example, `a LEFT JOIN b` is not equivalent to `b LEFT JOIN a`.

With that being said, when you have more than one join, the result should be interpreted carefully.

Consider

```
SELECT a.id,b.name,c.department
FROM
a INNER JOIN b on a.id = b.id  
LEFT JOIN c on a.id = c.id
```

The resulting table would consist of all `id` that is present in both `a` and `b`, and return `NULL` if a department is not present for those `id`.

So to answer your question, joins consider all your data in the query. However, the output table depends on the joins you used. If there are still confusion, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql) which addressed a similar thing.