# Are SQL inner joins reflexive?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Say you have two tables:

```
TA
- apk
- b
- a1

TB
- bpk
- b1
```

is the SQL `INNER JOIN` statement *[reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation)* in the way, that

```
SELECT TA.a1, TB.b1 FROM TA INNER JOIN TB ON TA.b = TB.bpk
```

is equivalent (in the way that the results are the same) to

```
SELECT TA.a1, TB.b1 FROM TB INNER JOIN TA ON TA.b = TB.bpk
```

?

Comment: Yes. order doesn't matter in `INNER JOIN` [**Related Post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql)

Comment: @1000111 thank you. Flagged this as a duplicate.

Comment: Similar to the way in which 4*8*7 = 7*4*8

Comment: @Strawberry this is why I searched for the term *reflexivity*. It is the reflexivity of the `*` operator, that allows you to randomly permute its arguments.