# Add default value if matching record is not found from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables

member

- id
- name
- address

tax_bill

- bill_id
- member_id
- tax_amount

tax_receipt

- receipt_id
- member_id
- paid_amount

Out put:

```
Name | Address | Tax | Paid Tax
ABC  | xyz     | 100 |100
PQR  | yte     | 200 | Not paid
```

here "not paid" is the default value which is not there in receipt table the record is only in member and bill table.

From above tables i want to show the member details with his bill detail and receipt details. Initially the tax_receipt will be empty, When the user will pay the tax, the entry will be in the tax_receipt detail. I want to create a report in which all the members detail from member table, tax detail from tax_bill and receipt detail from tax_receipt will be displayed. What i want is to show ZERO if the record is not found in tax_receipt table for perticular member's tax_bill details.

Also, i am using join query so it will be usefull if suggestion will be using join query.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This looks like a left join and using ISNULL() for the rows that have no matching values. Can you edit your question to include your query?

Comment: Actually i have more then these tables and the query is much longer then this and i am just stucked at this point only, so what i will do is from the suggestions i will implement in my query. Yet, this is the query i am using.

https://shrib.com/#4VxNgMBH8nO9rbVny9ew

Answer (score 1):

You seems want `left outer join` :

```
select m.Name, m.Address, txb.tax_amount as Tax, 
      isnull(cast(txr.paid_amount as varchar(255)), 'Not paid') as PaidTax 
from member m inner join
     tax_bill txb
     on txb.member_id = m.id left outer join
     tax_receipt txr
     on txr.receipt_id = txb.bill_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need (considering the example tables you provided):

```
select m.name, m.address, t.tax_amount, case when isnull(r.paid_amount, 0) = 0 then 'not paid' else cast(r.paid_amount as varchar(100)) end as paid_tax
from member m join tax_bill t on m.id = t.member_id
              left join tax_receipt r on m.id = r.member_id
```

There's a working copy [here](http://rextester.com/NNHW17716).

However, for your complicated long query mentioned in the comments, you should first format it so that it is legible, then read about [the importance of the join order when using left-right-full joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql#9615296) to join in the correct order for your needs and then try removing joins one by one to find out where your missing record gets lost.

Good luck!