# Employees working in all projects of a department

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

This is my database:

- Employee (**id**, *department_id*, name)
- Department(**id**, name)
- Project(**id**, *departament_id*)
- Work (***employee_id, project_id***)

With **PK**, *FK* (for example: Employee has PK id and FK departament_id (id) from Department)

**I want to select all the employees (E.name) that are working in all projects of a certain department (Development, for example).**

This is my query:

```
 SELECT E.name, 
        COUNT(P.id) AS PW, 
        AVG(DISTINCT(Q.allproj)) AS PrjOfDep
   FROM Employee E 
   JOIN WORK W 
     ON W.employee_id= E.id
   JOIN Project P 
     ON P.id = W.project_id
   JOIN (SELECT D.id, 
                COUNT(P1.id) AS allproj 
           FROM Project P1
           JOIN Department D 
             ON P1.departament_id = D.id
            AND D.name = "Development" 
       GROUP BY D.id) Q ON P.departament_id = Q.id
       GROUP BY E.ID HAVING PW = PrjOfDep
```

This is kinda working, this is the result:

```
Name    PW  PrjOfDep    
Stark   2   2.0000
Mike    2   2.0000
```

I didn't know how to check if all the projects where Employee E is working include all the projects of departament "development", so I did a trick and my query looks very ugly. I counted all the projects where Employee E is working in Development and I compared that with the number of project of Departament "Development".

PrjOfDep is an average, I did this ugly trick because the query

```
SELECT E.name, 
       COUNT(P.id) AS PW 
  FROM Employee E 
  JOIN WORK W 
    ON W.employee_id = E.id
  JOIN Project P 
    ON P.id= W.project_id
  JOIN (SELECT D.id, 
               COUNT(P1.id) AS allproj 
  FROM Project P1 
  JOIN Department D 
    ON P1.departament_id= D.id
   AND D.name = "Development" 
   GROUP BY D.id) Q 
    ON P.departament_id= Q.id
   GROUP BY E.id HAVING PW = Q.allproj
```

gives me the error:

```
 1054 - Unknown column 'Q.allproj' in 'having clause'
```

I want a more elegant query for my problem and I want to see only the name of the Employee. Thanks!

Comment: What is dnr and pnr?

Comment: The primary keys of Departament table and Project table

Comment: could you please provide some sample data

Comment: First... https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/ .. use naming conventions. Naming is there, for your and for anyone, to help understanding your code after forgetting anything you've done.

Comment: Ok, I will try to update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempts seem to be trying to do an awful lot more than what you have asked. If your question is simply how to

> **select all the employees (E.name) that are working in all project of a certain department (Development, for example).**

Then something like the following should work:

```
SELECT e.name
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Work w ON e.eid = w.eid
INNER JOIN Project p ON w.pid = p.pid
INNER JOIN Department d ON p.did = d.did
WHERE d.Deptname = "Development"
GROUP BY e.name
HAVING  COUNT(p.Projname) = (SELECT count(p.Projname)
                FROM Department d
                INNER JOIN Project p ON d.did = p.did
                WHERE d.Deptname = "Development")
```

Demo of this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/917676/10)

Comment: Excelent site, thanks! I have one more question: all joins are commutative in sql?

Comment: Order does not matter for `INNER` joins. This is because the inner join looks for data which exists in both tables only. Order does matter for `OUTER` joins though, and your query will return different results. For more information, see the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql

Comment: Hmm, your query is simple, but I want to see employees that are working in ALL projects of a certain department. Your query seem to return employees that are working in any project of a certain department

Comment: @4vol I have edited my solution. The above works, but I suspect it can be simplified. I will continue to test this solution and see if I can improve it further.

Comment: Piccini - Thanks, I've just tested your code and it works. I am curious whether is any other solution clearer and more elegant than that.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
SELECT
  EMP.*
FROM Employee EMP
JOIN Department DEP
ON 1 = 1
 AND DEP.did = EMP.did
WHERE 1 = 1
 AND DEP.Deptname = 'Development'
 AND EMP.eid NOT IN(    
  SELECT DISTINCT
    DEPEMP.eid
  FROM Employee DEPEMP
  JOIN Project PRO
  ON 1 = 1
   AND PRO.did = DEPEMP.did
  LEFT JOIN Work WRK
  ON 1 = 1
   AND WRK.eid = DEPEMP.eid
   AND WRK.pid = PRO.pid
  WHERE 1 = 1
   AND DEPEMP.did = DEP.did
   AND WRK.eid IS NULL
);
```

Sadly the solution is not that elegant.
Try it out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b79498/63/0)

Comment: "ON 1=1", "WHERE 1=1"... I don't really understant what you did there

Comment: You can completly ignore these. I just like to chain conditions always with an AND. So just erase the 1 = 1 AND. The query will remain the same.

Comment: Ok, but you code doens't work. Look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b79498/1

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Was to lazy to test it properly. I try again.

Comment: I fixed my solution, now it should by working for you.