# Does the order of columns in a SQL join statement matter?

Tags: sql

For instance, I might say this:

```
select * from a join b on a.AID = b.AID
```

Is this equivalent to

```
select * from a join b on b.AID = a.AID
```

? Or is there some difference?

Comment: No it doesn't matter or make any difference

Comment: No, this has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql

Comment: Consistency is nice, though, for ease of reading.

Comment: Column order does not matter. Join order does when using left or right joins. See links in aforementioned comments.