# Trying to join multiple tables in mysql - get error 1054, Unknown Column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I want to join multiple tables using JOINs, and mysql/mariadb is refusing to find one column. The column exists, of course, and I can't figure out what the cause might be.

**Table Layout**

```
CREATE TABLE `shops` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE `shops2categories` (
  `shopid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE `categories2items` (
  `itemid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
);
```

**Query:**
In order to avoid confusion with aliases, I now ran the query with the original table names.

```
SELECT
shops.name,
categories.name,
items.name

FROM shops

LEFT JOIN shops2categories ON shops2categories.shopid = shops.id
LEFT JOIN categories2items ON categories2items.categoryid = categories.id

LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = shops2categories.categoryid
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = categories2items.itemid
```

**Error Message:**

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'categories.id' in 'on clause'
```

No matter how I restructured my query (foreign key first, primary key first, items table first, categories table first, ..., using different JOIN types), I can't seem to get this to work. Also I read through a whole lot of SO questions to this topic, but I feel that the order is correct, I am not inserting nor updating, and it's not about quoting. Something is fundamentally broken in my concept, and I'm very keen on learning what this could be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the join order matter in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql)

Comment: `c.id` is referenced before the alias `c` is defined

Comment: @P.Salmon, thank you, I will have a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your `from` clause.  You reference `c.id` *before* you have defined `c`.

A table cannot be referenced until it is defined in the `FROM` clause.

You would seem to want:

```
FROM shops s LEFT JOIN
     shops2categories s2c
     ON s2c.shopid = s.id LEFT JOIN
     categories c
     ON c.id = s2c.categoryid LEFT JOIN
     categories2items c2i
     ON c2i.categoryid = c.id LEFT JOIN
     items i
     ON i.id = c2i.itemid
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! It didn't work out of the box, I had to use the table names without any aliases, but -- it works. Thanks!