# Writing a query to find many-many records without corresponding record in another many-many table

Tags: mysql, eloquent

I seek help for writing a query.

Some context:
I have the ff models

```
User(users) - id, name
Post (posts) - id, content
Bookmarks - user_id, post_id
Comment( comments) - id, content, post_id
Like(likes) - user_id, comment_id
```

I want to see which users have liked any comment in a post without bookmarking that particular post.

Currently i write the query like this, but it return empty result.

```
Like::leftJoin('comments', 'likes.comment_id', '=', 'comments.id')
    ->leftJoin('bookmarks', 'bookmarks.post_id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
    ->whereNull('bookmarks.post_id')
    ->pluck('likes.user_id')
```

```
select likes.user_id from likes 
left join bookmarks on bookmarks.post_id = comments.post_id
left join comments on likes.comment_id = comments.id
where bookmarks.post_id is null
```

I expect it to return list of user_id without corresponding bookmarks.
It returns an empty list instead.

Comment: And what does it return than?

Comment: It returns an empty list here.

Comment: 'I expect it to return list of user_id without corresponding bookmarks' - there seems to be no reason to invoke comments in your query given user_id exists in bookmarks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the join order matter in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614922/does-the-join-order-matter-in-sql)

Comment: @P.Salmon 
I invoke comments in the query because, i need to check that the bookmark post_id is same as comment post_id post.

Comment: Change the order of the joins, remove the null check and representative sample data as text

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate the change in join order that your question suggests. You are also missing the join criterion for `user_id` between `likes` and `bookmarks`. I think it should be:

```php
Like::join('comments', 'likes.comment_id', '=', 'comments.id')
    ->leftJoin('bookmarks', function ($join) {
        $join->on('bookmarks.post_id', '=', 'comments.post_id');
        $join->on('bookmarks.user_id', '=', 'likes.user_id');
    })
    ->whereNull('bookmarks.post_id')
    ->distinct()
    ->pluck('likes.user_id');
```